# What is the function of jumper pins on a 4 channel relay?

Tags: power-electronics, electronics

Attached is a picture of a 4 channel relay. I have searched the internet for the function of the jumpers circled in red. They are labelled Low Com and High. On all sites which I have looked at they are labelled JD-VCC VCC and GND.

[image]

Comment: I think this should be posted here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ while some of us have electronics experience, if you're after an 'electrical engineer', then look there.

Answer (score 3):

Each channel can be set to be triggered high or low.
[image]
See [User Manual](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/qFRG4FIijiQC927FcUf8K331Cx5lKCAMiIHzzwqdjr4/bpaJHm35Sj2TqyE9J25WnA?_encoding=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0&mgh=1)

Comment: What is considered a high level trigger selection, and what is considered a low level trigger selection?

Comment: @checkmate, the answer to your question can be found at end of document by posted by *StainlessSteelRat*. I have posted a snip [below](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/37399/110) to help you find the information

Comment: If you look at your board or the image, high/low settings are written on there.  If you download the User Manual, maybe all this information is available.

Answer (score 0):

A high level and low level trigger can be configured as the follows.

[image]

**Note:** This information can be found at end of the document from [this](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/37387/110) post

**Reference:**

- [Configurable Active High or Low Relay Module, with opto-isolated input](https://youtu.be/4oPFm2tyM58?t=20)
- [2 Channel 5V Relay Module](http://2%20Channel%205V%20Relay%20Module)